# Obj-C / iPhone: NSArray question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array that looks like this when printed via NSLog:

```
{
response = "Valid";
updates = (
         {
         string = "test";
         integer = 3493;
         },
         {
         string = "test2";
         integer = 55454;
         }
         );
start-index = 0;
```

My question is how I can loop through through the "updates" array so that I may print the values for each "string" respectively.

Should be an easy "for" loop or something?

Dave

Comment: I guess my real question is, how can I make a new array out of "updates"?

Comment: That is not an array. Arrays don't have keys, they have numeric indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you NSLogged data has a type of NSDictionary with name data.

```
NSArray *updates = [data objectForKey:@"updates"];
for (NSDictionary *update in updates) {
    NSLog(@"Update: %@ - %@", [update objectForKey:@"string"], [update objectForKey:@"integer"]);
}
```